# Raster flips our image upside down

Tags: image-processing

We are working with this image:

[image]

And we are trying a project with singular value decomposition. Here is our approach:

We start by importing the image, which has this filename on our system, but it is the image above.

```
image = Import["DSC_0880-7.jpg"]
```

Then we do this:

```
A = ImageData[ImageTake[image, {1, 480}, {1, 640}], "Byte"];
```

Then we adjusted something we found on the web to help us:

```
Approximate[A_, k_] := Module[
   {approximateImage},
   {U, Σ, VT} = SingularValueDecomposition[N[A], k];
   approximateImage = Graphics[
     Raster[
      U.Σ.Transpose[VT]/
       Max[U.Σ.Transpose[VT]]],
     PlotLabel -> 
      "Singular Values: " <> ToString[NumberForm[k, 3]] <> 
       "     Compression: " <>
       ToString[
        NumberForm[
         100*
          k*(1. Dimensions[A][[1]] + 
             Dimensions[A][[2]])/(Dimensions[A][[1]]*
             Dimensions[A][[2]])
          "% of Original.", 2]
        ]
     ]
   ];
```

Then we try this:

```
Show[Approximate[A, 20]]
```

But our image is flipped upside down.

[image]

Can someone help us unflip our image?

Comment: Please read the relevant answer in [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32377/731), hopefully it will clear things up. I don't think there's much to do about it, other than flipping it back.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`DataReversed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataReversed.html) option of [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageData.html).

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}];

Graphics[Raster@ImageData[img, DataReversed -> True]]
```

[image]

This discrepancy between `Image` and `Raster` is due to the differences in standard coordinate systems in image processing / matrices (top to bottom) and function plotting ($y$ axis points up):

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html#1708646374

Comment: @Szaboics Thanks to the help. My student really appreciated the response.